# add disabled (and selected) option to select item with form helper

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

hi
I'm trying to add a disabled option to a select box with the form helper I use this code to generate an extra empty field, but I want this field disabled.

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.usertype_id',array('type'=>'select', 'empty'=>'usertype');
```

this generates:

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="UserUsertypeId">Usertype</label>
    <select name="data[User][usertype_id]" id="UserUsertypeId">
        <option value="">usertype</option>
        <option value="1">athlete</option>
        <option value="2">trainer</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

but I want this:

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="UserUsertypeId">Usertype</label>
    <select name="data[User][usertype_id]" id="UserUsertypeId">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">usertype</option>
        <option value="1">athlete</option>
        <option value="2">trainer</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this simply, or should I just use some js?

Answer (score 10):

If you know the options in advance, you can build the `$options` array to use in the select menu. This should give you exactly what you want:

```
$options = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'usertype',
                'value' => '',
                'disabled' => TRUE,
                'selected' => TRUE
            ),
            'athlete',
            'trainer'
            );

echo $this->Form->input('User.usertype_id', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $options));
```

<del>Or possibly this might work, but I haven't tested it either:</del>

<del>echo $this->Form->input('User.usertype_id', array('type' => 'select', 'empty'=> array('text' => 'usertype', 'selected' => TRUE, 'disabled' => FALSE)));</del>

Comment: Working fine .. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was last updated in 2010, but I have the actual answer.
Look at the example from the CakePHP docs:

```
$options = array(
    'Value 1' => 'Label 1',
    'Value 2' => 'Label 2'
);
echo $this->Form->select('Model.field', $options, array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'disabled' => array('Value 1')
));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select

Answer (score 2):

Try this one!!

```
$operations = [
  '' => 'Select Operation',
  'query' => 'Query',
  'create' => 'Create',
  'update' => 'Update',
  'upsert' => 'Upsert',
  'delete' => 'Delete'
];

echo $this->Form->input('operation[]',[
  'type' => 'select',
  'options' => $operations,
  'class' => 'operation-class',
  'id' => 'operation-id-1',
  'required' => 'required',
  'label' => false,
  'disabled' => [''],
  'value' => ''
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

mhmm looks like it isn't possible to add some codeblocks to a comment
so, both of your options generated:

```
<select name="data[User][usertype_id]" id="UserUsertypeId">
  <option value="text">usertype</option>
  <option value="selected">1</option>
  <option value="disabled"></option>
  <option value="1">athlete</option>
  <option value="2">trainer</option>
</select>
```

so this didn't work, but I did it this way:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.usertype_id', array('type' => 'select', 'empty'=> array('text" disabled="disabled" selected="selected' => '')));
```

this generates an option with the value: (" disabled="disabled" selected="selected)
so it becomes:

```
...
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
...
```

this is a temporary solution, until I find something better, suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Check out my answer again. I've edited the first option so that it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I merge the solution of Weptunus and stevelove.

In the controller:

```
$examples = $this->Test->Examples->find('list');
$this->set('examples', $examples);
```

In the view

```
echo $this->Form->input('example_id', array('empty' => array(
        '' => array(
            'name' => __('Select an Example'),
            'value' => '',
            'disabled' => TRUE,
            'selected' => TRUE
        )
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found this success in cake 1.3

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('example', array('type' => 'select','id' => 'id','options' => array('empty "disabled="disabled" selected="selected"' => 'name empty', 'val1' => 'text1', 'val2' => 'text2')); ?>
```